# How to mount an ISO image to a specific folder in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, mount, iso-image

Would like to mount an windows ISO in a specific folder (/mnt/win7x64). The only thing I can do is mount using `hdiutil mount windows.iso` but it goes to /Volumes/something.
The linux command `mount -o loop,ro windows.iso somefolder` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that you are running macOS, not Linux. On the former, the preferred command to `mount` is `hdiutil`, which as you said you had success with. You just needed to read further down the man page until you found `-mountroot path` flag.

So assuming you already created and own `/mnt` folder, your correct command would be:

```
% hdiutil attach windows.iso -mountroot /mnt/win7x64
```

The Apple engineers prefer the term `attach` to `mount`, as this is an disk image and not a physical disk.

One final note, this command still will display an icon of your mounted ISO on your Desktop. If this is not desired, throw the `-nobrowse` flag. The man page is your friend.